# How to load csv file to Hive table with multiline columns

Tags: hive

My csv file
41550,0.421273148,Security,Success Audit,Logon/Logoff ,538,ABACUS-CC\AC-STM-36091$',PK-LHR-CC-SV01,"User Logoff;User Name:AC-STM-36091$
    Domain:     ABACUS-CC
    Logon ID:       (0x0,0x55669B6F)
    Logon Type: 3
"

desired is
41550,0.421273148,Security,Success Audit,Logon/Logoff ,538,ABACUS-CC\AC-STM-36091$',PK-LHR-CC-SV01,"User Logoff;User Name:AC-STM-36091$ Domain: ABACUS-CC Logon ID: (0x0,0x55669B6F) Logon Type: 3 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use

```
  create table mytable (<columns) ..   
             **lines terminated by** 
            <choose something besides \n>
```